# How can I let my visitors compare (and rate) two images displayed from a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have set up a mysql database that holds an image (more specifically a path to an image) and the images rank (starting at 0). I then created a web page that displays two images at random at a time. [Up till here everything works fine] I want my users to be able to click on one of the images that they like better and for that images rank to increase by +1 in the database.

How would I set that up? Please be as detailed as possible in your explanation. I am new to php and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

onclick execute `UPDATE image_ranks SET rank = rank+1 WHERE image_id = {$image_id}`

implement onclick event for image ( or voting icon ) what will execute AJAX request to script which will update rank value in database, as result will return a new updated value what can be used to update <div> content with acctual ranking

Comment: Thanks for the response @bensiu. 
My next question for you is how I would implement that piece of code? From what I read you cannot use onclick events with php.

Comment: onclick (choosing image to vote up) is not happend in PHP it need to be done in JS on browser side, eg as AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

A Table

**Images:** 
ID,Name,Path,ranking

- Have One up vote button ( update images set ranking = ranking + 1 where id = $id; )
- Have One down vote button ( update images set ranking = ranking - 1 where id = $id and ranking > 0; )

Hopefully that solves the problem.